# Text editor playing hide and seek

Tags: 11.10, unity, gedit, text, editor

When ever I minimise or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> from the text editor Gedit, it disappears from Unity and from alt tabbing. I can open a new instance of it from the menu, but all previous work is lost. How can I fix this?

Comment: What text-editor are you using?

Comment: What happens when you try to run it from the terminal? Is there any output?

Comment: I am using gEdit and when I run it from the terminal I do get the previous instance with my work back. But it still disappears from Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I just updated the system. maybe it could work for you.

Comment: I am using 11.10.

Comment: i meant checking for updates.

Comment: There is no updates to install.

Comment: try unlocking the application from the launcher then locking to the launcher.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work.